# Timedelta returned by tzinfo object

Tags: python, timezone

I'm studying datetimes in python and have come to timezones. I created a Pacific `timezone` with a `timedelta`

```py
pacific = datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(hours=8))
```

Then, I created an **aware** `datetime` object which I converted to pacific with the `tzinfo` object

```py
aware = datetime.datetime(2020,12,20,11, tzinfo=pacific)
```

**aware** returns a `timedelta` and I would like to know what it's calculating. It's `-1, 57600`

```py
print(aware)

>>> datetime.datetime(2020,12,20,11,0, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(-1,57600))
```

Comment: in your code example, it says `hours=8` - US/Pacific is UTC-8; did you mean `hours=-8`? by the way, what you created is a static offset from UTC, static meaning it e.g. won't have DST. have a look at Python's [zoneinfo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html) module for more "advanced" time zone handling.

Comment: Yes, it should have been -8. Little typo error there. And thanks for the link, the material I'm studying is very basic so this will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

What's happening here is that there are two ways to represent the time zone shift.

You can represent it by the time delta of 28800 seconds (8 hours behind UTC time). Or equivalently you can represent it by going back 1 day (the -1) and then adding 57600 seconds. This also gives you 28800 seconds (8 hours) behind UTC for pacific.

Comment: Thank you for that answer. I would have never figured that out!

Comment: would you mind upvoting/accepting? thx, max

Comment: I think this is incorrect. US/Pacific is at UTC-8, so the correct static tz would be `datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(hours=-8))`. Other than that, `days=-1, seconds=57600` is just how Python represents (`__repr__`) a timedelta of -8 hours.

Comment: You are correct, it should be -8. The user just needs help with general understanding. I don't think it matters that much